# Duplication of multiple table sql

Tags: sql

```
SELECT c1, c2, c3
FROM 
(SELECT * FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table2
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table3
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table4) data
GROUP BY c1, c2, c2
HAVING (COUNT(*) > 1)
```

I cant find only duplicate rows that are in common. This query demostrates all datas in common example data table 1 and 2 .. i want only the data that are in comon of all tables any help?

Comment: Can you please post some sample data explaining how this query doesn't work? also What RDBMS you are using?

Answer (score 3):

This will return duplicate records found in all four tables

```
SELECT c1,c2,c3
FROM   (
           SELECT *
           FROM   table1
           UNION ALL
           SELECT *
           FROM   table2
           UNION ALL
           SELECT *
           FROM   table3
           UNION ALL
           SELECT *
           FROM   table4
       ) DATA
GROUP BY c1, c2, c3
HAVING (COUNT(*) >3)
```

Answer (score 2):

One more option with [INTERSECT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) in SQLServer2005+

```
SELECT c1, c2, c3
FROM Table1
INTERSECT
SELECT c1, c2, c3
FROM Table2
INTERSECT
SELECT c1, c2, c3
FROM Table3
INTERSECT
SELECT c1, c2, c3
FROM Table4
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is a typo or not but in your `GROUP BY` clause, there is no `c3` and you have double `c2`. It should be

```
SELECT c1, c2, c3
FROM 
    (
        SELECT * FROM table1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM table2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM table3
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM table4
    ) data
GROUP BY c1, c2, c3
HAVING (COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want all the records that are common in each of the tables, use an `INNER JOIN` on each table:

```
SELECT t1.c1, t1.c2, t1.c3
FROM Table1 t1
    INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.c1 = t2.c1 AND t1.c2 = t2.c2 AND t1.c3 = t2.c3
    INNER JOIN Table3 t3 ON t1.c1 = t3.c1 AND t1.c2 = t3.c2 AND t1.c3 = t3.c3
    INNER JOIN Table4 t4 ON t1.c1 = t4.c1 AND t1.c2 = t4.c2 AND t1.c3 = t4.c3
```

This will return you all matching records from each table.

And here is a sample [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/591ca/1).

Comment: example i have table with 7000 rows, table with 3000 rows and table with 2000 rows. I want to show me rows that are in common to 3 tables . This query shows me rows that are in common between 1-2 1-3 2-3 . So the idea is to show only rows that are in common betwen 1-2-3

Comment: @user2083513 -- this should show you the rows that are in common with all the tables.

Comment: @user2083513 -- np, glad we could help :)